# Cannot remove docker image

Tags: docker

I'm getting an error that image cannot be deleted because it's used by a container. The problem is that I've just removed all containers. Can this glitch be fixed without removing docker entirely?

Comment: Did you run the `docker ps -a` command to determine that there are no containers at all (as opposed to no containers running)? Also, when one Docker image is dependent upon the image you are trying to delete, you need to delete the dependent image first

Comment: @ChrisSc both docker ui and console say that there are no containers, which makes sense, considering that I have removed them previously. I have also tried removing images one by one to ensure that they do not depend on each other, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I have 5 images left and they all cannot be deleted, error message says that they are used by a container. Which is a false info, since there are no containers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a stopped container running. You can check it with `$ docker ps -a`

If you have a stopped container you can run `$ docker container rm -f container-id` and then you will be able to remove the image.

Instead you could run `$ docker image rm -f image-name`.
The `-f` flag will force the image deletation even if you have a running container using that image. The command doesn't stop/remove your container.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but as I said in the main post - I have removed all containers. I suppose there is no other way but to reinstall docker entirely. Which is quite problematic, but even up to date version of docker remains glitched.